# jquery weekcalendar resize/drop variables current div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am customizing the jquery weekcalendar to use json to read/write data to a mysql database.

What works so far, loading the cal from db, creating and storing new events on cal and deleting events on the calendar.

I run into problems trying to get the time/date variables when you resize an event on the calendar.

Selecting all the values for the events is possible but I don't know how to get the current resized event.

So far I have:

```
eventResize : function(calEvent, $event) {
      var startField = $(".wc-time").text();
      alert(startField);
  },
```

This selects all the calendar event times but I only need the one that I just resized.

Any toughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this wiki](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/) the event `eventResize` is called with three parameters and the last one is the element that was resized.

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't tought of checking $element. For other people reading this, $element is an object that contains 4 keys.

Start -> date,
End -> date,
title -> text,
Body -> text

You can get the keys and values by iterating trough the object with jquery easily.